# grub-install failure, and grub2 failure in general

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I asked in [another topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392240/) about Grub hanging in the shell. I installed Ubuntu Studio from a Live USB, alongside Windows 8.1, but encountered this problem -- with help I was able to at least get into the new OS. Now the second half of the problem (that Grub isn't working in the first place) is almost a separate issue, so I've created a separate question and hopefully I can provide more information than at first.

I got into the OS as described in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366001):

```
$ linux (hd0,gpt8)/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/sda8
$ initrd (hd0,gpt8)/boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-14-generic
$ boot
```

Once I was in, I did more research to find a solution to the overall issue, and I thought I had found it in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140785): I booted into my live USB, and ran these commands, and got output as follows.

```
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ mkdir tmp
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda8 /home/ubuntu-studio/tmp
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu-studio/tmp /dev/sda
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

So, now I don't know how to proceed. What's the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run boot-repair, and check the option that says 'Backup and rename Windows EFI files.'

The BIOS wants to boot only Windows and nothing else, because (I am taking some poetic license) it is a foolish BIOS indeed.

boot-repair will rename our EFI to trick BIOS.

Formatting my HD didn't do the trick because the BIOS itself had some things backed up apparently. At least, that's what I understand, I may be wrong on that last bit.